# Where is RabbitMQ config file, as its log shows "config file(s) : (none)"

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and have newly installed RabbitMQ 3.7.17 on a test virtual machine, it runs OK and I'm able to log in on its web interface.

I'm looking at some unclear notes left by the previous engineer, mentioning some required configuration changes of `management.listener.port = 9999` and `management.listener.ip   = 0.0.0.0`. Tentatively I think these items belong to the configuration keys of RabbitMQ, so I hope to locate the file and confirm.

I checked the log file `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@payv.log`, and it contains `config file(s) : (none)` at the beginning. I also tried command `rabbitmq-diagnostics status -n rabbit@payv` and the output contains nothing about `config`.

I found another file `/usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server-3.7.17/rabbitmq.config.example` but not sure if this is the sample to create the configuration file from.

My questions are:

- I need to confirm `management.listener.port` and `management.listener.ip` are indeed the configuration keys.
- Where is the configuration file located, and how to create it if it is missing?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated, and just let me know if you need more information.

**More of the log file:**

```
2021-08-11 16:41:40.648 [info] <0.8.0> Log file opened with Lager
2021-08-11 16:41:41.380 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-08-11 16:41:41.380 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-08-11 16:41:41.404 [info] <0.220.0>
 Starting RabbitMQ 3.7.17 on Erlang 21.3.8.6
 Copyright (C) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
 Licensed under the MPL.  See https://www.rabbitmq.com/
2021-08-11 16:41:41.404 [info] <0.220.0>
 node           : rabbit@payv
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : (none)
 cookie hash    : bpwgtZuS4DLf4bvseoUPpQ==
 log(s)         : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@payv.log
                : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@payv_upgrade.log
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@payv
2021-08-11 16:41:41.410 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step pre_boot defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.410 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.410 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_alarm defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.415 [info] <0.226.0> Memory high watermark set to 1515 MiB (1589220147 bytes) of 3788 MiB (3973050368 bytes) total
2021-08-11 16:41:41.418 [info] <0.228.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring
2021-08-11 16:41:41.418 [info] <0.228.0> Disk free limit set to 50MB
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step code_server_cache defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step file_handle_cache defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.231.0> Limiting to approx 32668 file handles (29399 sockets)
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.232.0> FHC read buffering:  OFF
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.232.0> FHC write buffering: ON
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step worker_pool defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.421 [info] <0.221.0> Will use 4 processes for default worker pool
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.221.0> Starting worker pool 'worker_pool' with 4 processes in it
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step database defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Node database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@payv is empty. Assuming we need to join an existing cluster or initialise from scratch...
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Configured peer discovery backend: rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Will try to lock with peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Peer discovery backend does not support locking, falling back to randomized delay
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config does not support registration, skipping randomized startup delay.
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> All discovered existing cluster peers:
2021-08-11 16:41:41.422 [info] <0.220.0> Discovered no peer nodes to cluster with
2021-08-11 16:41:41.423 [info] <0.43.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
2021-08-11 16:41:41.493 [info] <0.220.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2021-08-11 16:41:41.506 [info] <0.220.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config does not support registration, skipping registration.
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step database_sync defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step feature_flags defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step codec_correctness_check defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step external_infrastructure defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_registry defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.535 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_auth_mechanism_cr_demo defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_random defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_event defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_auth_mechanism_amqplain defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_auth_mechanism_plain defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_type_direct defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_type_fanout defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_type_headers defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_type_topic defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_mode_all defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_mode_exactly defined by app rabbit
2021-08-11 16:41:41.536 [info] <0.220.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_mode_nodes defined by app rabbit
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in /etc/rabbitmq/ for a file similar to rabbitmq.conf.
Could also be in /data/configuration/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

More info to be found i the docs https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just checked the system, the configuration file is not at the locations: 1) `/etc/rabbitmq/` contains nothing but file `enabled_plugins`; and 2) `/data/` contains nothing about RabbitMQ either.

File `/usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server-3.7.17/rabbitmq.config.example` seems to be of the RabbitMQ sample configuration file in [the old classic format of Erlang terms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-formats), I'm not sure if I should generate the configuration file from this sample.